# Member should be declared before all private instance

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, eslint

```
private userSubject$: BehaviorSubject<UserModel> = new BehaviorSubject<UserModel>(null);
userChanged$: Observable<UserModel> = this.userSubject$.asObservable();
```

It says:

> Member userChanged$ should be declared before all private instance
> field definitions.eslint@typescript-eslint/member-ordering

I like this rule. But how can I use the above code without disabling this rule?

If I'll change the order then it says:

> Property 'userSubject$' is used before its initialization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can move the initialization into the constructor:

```js
userChanged$: Observable<UserModel>;

private userSubject$: BehaviorSubject<UserModel>;

constructor() {
    this.userSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<UserModel>(null);
    this.userChanged$ = this.userSubject$.asObservable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "get" for the observable:

```
private _userSubject: BehaviorSubject<UserModel> = new BehaviorSubject<UserModel>(null);

get getUserSubject$(): Observable<UserModel> {
    return this._userSubject.asObservable();
}
```